# not_analyzed in mapping is ignored

Tags: perl, elasticsearch, kibana

TLDR : Some fields are analyzed even though the mapping says not_analyzed.

I have several sets of data, each is sent to an Elasticsearch index based on the date included in the set (which gives index names like index-25012016). Some sets have the same date and therefore the same index.

I use the following perl command to send the mapping to ES

`` print  `curl -s -XPUT "http://$ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL/$currentIndexName?pretty" -d ' $mapping'` ``

where $currentIndexName and $mapping are strings that respectively looks like `index-25012016` and

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "myMappingType": {
            "properties": {
                "present": {
                    "type":"boolean"
                },
                "records": {
                    "type":"integer"
                },
                "batchID": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "index":"not_analyzed"
                },
                "version": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "index":"not_analyzed"
                },
                "date": {
                    "type":"date",
                    "format":"yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
                "packageCreationDate": {
                    "type":"date",
                    "format":"MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with a few more fields.
This command is repeated for all sets, except for any $currentIndexName I have already done previously. 
When the command is run, the answer from ES is

```
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
```

Whether this mapping step was skipped or achieved, I then send the data to ES with `` `curl -s -XPOST "$ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL/$currentIndexName/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary \@$outputFileName`; ``
where $outputFileName is the name of a json file.

The problem is that even though I specify not_analyzed, in Kibana/Settings/Indices, the string fields are marked both analyzed and indexed, where I just want indexed. Therefore, for example, since the version field is the same for all ("3.2.506 64-bit"), a pie chart will show three equal slices of "3.2.506", "64" and "bit" instead of a whole unsliced "3.2.506 64-bit" pie. The boolean, number, date fields and meta-fields, though, are not analyzed.

The index pattern in Kibana matches all those indexes (index-*) and uses date as the time-based event field.
I tried to recreate the index pattern after the data is sent, it doesn't change anything.
I'm on Windows 7 and don't use logstash.

EDIT : Since I do a lot of testing at the moment, every time the script starts, I remove the data before iterating over the sets with
    `` print `curl -s -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/index-*?pretty`; ``
Therefore the script looks like :

```
Remove data  
for each set in allSets 
    mapping (if not already mapped in a previous iteration)  
    send data to ES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings for existing data cannot be updated. You need to create a new index with the correct mappings and reindex your documents into that index. Here is the link to ES docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_updating_existing_mappings

You can also use index templates to apply mapping to newly created indices automatically: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: Thank you, you reminded me I forgot to write something important : I actually delete the data before I start the process (see edited answer). Therefore doesn't the mapping step create the index, to which I then send the data ?

Comment: Does ES return correct mapping for your index when you perform GET request to http://localhost:9200/your-index-name?pretty=true after your script completed? If so, I would try refreshing field list in Kibana for the index pattern. If this won't work, then maybe there are still old indices with the old mapping present that match the Kibana index pattern? Anyway, take a look at index templates I mentioned, since they will apply correct mappings on index creation and you won't need to modify mapping by yourself.

Comment: Still not sure why it didn't work before, but using automatic index templates did the trick. Thank you.